# How to access this dictionary of dictionaries with a numbered index in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary of dictionaries like this;

```
{ 'A': {'xx': '2', 'yy': '3'}, 'B': {'xx': '4', 'yy': '5'} }
```

I want to be able to access this dictionary via a number index.

I would like to change it to something that looks like this;

```
[{'key': 'A', 'xx': '2', 'yy': '3'}, {'key':'B', 'xx': '4', 'yy': '5'}]
```

How can this be done in Python? I am using Python 2.7

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Question was edited after the initial answers. Sorry, I was not clear exactly what I wanted until the initial answers appeared.

Comment: That is incorrect syntax. You cannot have `(a : ...)`. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I think your initial approach is fine. No need to change anything

Comment: @sshashank124: I am sorry I am still weak in my Python to correct the syntax. I only need to be able to be able to access the dictionary with an index. Don't care what structure is used. Thank you.

Comment: You mean like `my_dict[1]` instead of `my_dict['B']`?

Comment: what u want to access for example A and its value

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Thanks!! The problem with dictionary is that they are not ordered like list and tuples. But the advantage with them is they have key->value which is absent from list and tuples. I need to combine the best of both worlds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b={ 'A': {'xx': '2', 'yy': '3'}, 'B': {'xx': '4', 'yy': '5'} }
```

below is to check whether ur index such as 'A', 'B' are in dict and if they are there u can fetch them `by b[<ur index>]`

```
if 'A' in b.keys():
    print b['A']
c=[]
```

below function is used to get all the key and values of dict

```
 for key,value in b.items():
        c.append(value)

print c
#output:[{'xx': '2', 'yy': '3'}, {'xx': '4', 'yy': '5'}]
```

after the edit

```
c=[]

for key,value in b.items():
        value['key']=key
        c.append(value)
#output:[{'yy': '3', 'xx': '2', 'key': 'A'}, {'yy': '5', 'xx': '4', 'key': 'B'}]
```

Comment: Sorry I made some changes to the original question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3293156 that is easy . u can also get that out put

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, you can do it using `dict.values()`:

```
x = { 'A': {'xx': '2', 'yy': '3'}, 'B': {'xx': '4', 'yy': '5'}}

>>> x = x.values()
[{'xx': '2', 'yy': '3'}, {'xx': '4', 'yy': '5'}]
```

Now, you can access the values as `x[0]` and `x[1]` instead of `x['A']` and `x['B']`

Comment: What if I want to change the output to `[{'key': 'A', 'xx': '2', 'yy': '3'}, {'key':'B', 'xx': '4', 'yy': '5'}]` ? I have modified the question accordingly. Thanks for your help.